# Python Add units to dataframe

Tags: python, units-of-measurement

I am trying to add units to a dataframe and am having trouble getting around the rows that have blanks. Here is what I have:

```
Index |   Inch   |  mm  |  ft
______________________________
 0    |         |   4   |   7
______________________________
 1    |    2     |      |   8
______________________________
 2    |    3     |   6  |   9
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
    if numbers.find('\d') > -1:
            return str(round_string_float(numbers))+' in'
```

But this wont use regex to find numbers. Here is what I am trying to get:

```
Index |   Inch   |  mm    |    ft
______________________________________
 0    |          |  4 mm  |   7 ft
______________________________________
 1    |   2 in   |        |   8 ft
______________________________________
 2    |   3 in   |  6 mm  |   9 ft
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
df['Inch'] = df['Inch'].fillna('').astype(str) + ' in'
```

To add the "in", and then:

```
df.loc[df['Inch'] == ' in', 'Inch'] = ''
```

To get rid of the lines without numbers.
And so on for all the columns.

Comment: The first one did add 'in' but it added it to the blanks as well as the rows with a number in the column

Comment: @ShawnJamal Did you also write the second line to delete those cells, as I wrote?

Comment: Nevermind! I forgot to rename the column from "Inch' to the column name in my DF. It works like a charm. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.apply` with `Series.str.replace`:

```
new_df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace("(\d+)", "\\1 %s" % x.name, regex=True))
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
         Inch    mm    ft
Index                    
0              4 mm  7 ft
1      2 Inch        8 ft
2      3 Inch  6 mm  9 ft
```

Comment: Unfortunately the column names are a little more complex than the question but thanks for the try.